# What does "Turing-complete" really mean?

Tags: logic, computability

People talk about various programming languages or computational models being "Turing-complete."  But what does that technically mean?  The technical definition is buried under tons of informal "definitions", and is too basic to be covered by textbooks I have at hand (including Odifreddi's, a textbook that tends to talk about this kind of topic).

A plausible definition is this: fix some standard computational model.  For a programming language $L$, let $K_L$ be the set of (codes) of triplets $(e,x,y)$ where $e$ is (the code of) a program in $L$ and $y$ is the result of running $e$ with input $x$.  For decent $L$, $K_L$ is r.e.  And $L$ is defined to be Turing-complete if $K_L \equiv_T 0'$.

For all natural $L$, not only $K_L \equiv_T 0'$ but also $K_L \equiv_m 0'$ (or equivalently $K_L \equiv_1 0'$).  That is, there exist computable functions $c, i, o$ such that $(c(e),i(x),o(y)) \in K_L$ iff $\varphi_{e}(x) \downarrow= y$.  Intuitively, $c$ can be thought of as a compiler, and $i$ and $o$ can be seen as functions that changes the "format" of input and output. (*Edit*: in the first few editions of this post the function went in the wrong direction.)

But there exists an r.e. set $S$ s.t. $S \equiv_T 0'$ but $S \not \equiv_m 0'$, like effective simple sets.  By reinterpreting $S$ as a set of triplets one can think of a programming language $L_S$ such that $K_{L_S} = S$.  This $L$ lacks at least one of the functions $c,i,o$ above.  Such a language seems really bizarre, albeit being "Turing-complete."  Most non-$m$-complete $T$-complete sets are artificial, but there are some not-so-artificial ones, like the set of non-Kolmogorov random strings.

Do we call such $L_S$ Turing-complete?  Or does it have a different definition?

Comment: Fix some totally formal convention for Turing machines (e,g, fix the number of tapes, whether the head can read and move in the same step, the number of symbols in the language, a standard coding of $\mathbb{N}$ etc (also make these conventions reasonable)). Then for a fixed program $e$ you can define a partial function $f_e(x)=y$ iff when you run the machine $e$ on input $x$ it halts and outputs $y$. The class of all such functions are the Turing computible functions, and a different model is Turing complete if it can compute all these functions. That's it.

Comment: @James Is it equivalent to $K_L \equiv_T 0'$, $K_L \equiv_m 0'$ or neither? (I know there's some sloppiness in what I wrote since partial functions should be single-valued)

Comment: You want to interpret every set equivalent to $0'$ as the halting set for some encoding of the recursive functions? It's tough as you don't define what counts as a "programming language". I imagine you will want it to be false for $\equiv_T$, as you would expect the halting set to always be c.e. which is not true for arbitrary sets in the $T$ degree of $0'$, for $m$ degrees, I'm not sure, maybe you could cook something up. It certainly isn't going to give you the "meaning" of Turing completeness though.

Comment: @James For T-degree, I am only thinking of r.e. sets (I've updated the statement to make this clear.) For m-degree, isn't it just true that every complete set is the halting set for some encoding, since they are all recursively isomorphic? (I'm reasoning sloppy.)

Comment: I suppose you are right for $m$ degrees, but then the way you decode your program from $e$ is something like: "apply $f$ then decode $f(e)$ using the standard conventions" which, isn't particularly natural.

Comment: I think the problem is that Turing completeness is a property of "programming languages" (or some very similar notion) and your sets of triples $(e, x, y)$ don't capture the intensional aspects of a programming language. So your difficulty seems to me to be the same as the difficulty of formalising the Church-Turing thesis.

Comment: I think that this question should be posted on a different website. One that has more to do with programming languages and perhaps theoretical computer science.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I think the question is well within the sphere of mathematical logic, so I don't think it is inappropriate on MSE.

Comment: @Rob: That might be, but it seems to me that the question will be better served on a site whose users are foremost programmers and computer scientists. Since the question is explicitly asking what does it mean for a computer programming language to be Turing complete. It's more a question about programming language, than it is about abstract computability and logic.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: surely the Church-Turing thesis is in the scope of MSE, even if the answer in MSE is just to say something about the boundaries of mathematics and to pass the question on to philosophy or computer science as appropriate.

Comment: @Rob: ***I'm not saying that it's not on topic!*** Just like I'm not saying that any statistics question should be asked on stats.SE either. What I am saying, however, is that this question may benefit from being moved to another site. So far about half the discussion is whether or not it should be moved, and no answer was posted.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I myself do not think that my question might well be moved.  My question is also applicable to coding schema of partial computable functions that are not of interest in theory of programming languages - like codes of Turing machines.  Also pathologies I mentioned like m-complete non-T-complete sets are more about abstract computability and logic, I think.  I can't deny the possibility of interesting answers coming out from theoretical computer scientists, though.

Comment: Why not post it on both sites, @AsafKaragila?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm asking, at least in part, because I don't know the policy on cross-posting to other SE sites and I reckon you do. Note that this question seems to be an example of why cross-posting is sometimes appropriate.